# Instagram API: How can I search for hashtags?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

From what I'm seeing, I can't search for hashtags unless I have the public_content permission.

And I can't get the public_content permission unless I submit an app for review.

And I can't submit an app for review unless I have a video screencast and a very good reason as to why I need this permission. I just build websites for clients and they want to pull in posts that have one of their own hashtags. I don't see this on the list of approved application types.

Or is there another way to search for hashtags without having to go through all this?

Comment: There is no other way to get hashtags without public_content permission. For public_content permission you must submit your api for review.

Answer (score 0):

while requesting code you may pass scope as `public_content`

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=public_content`

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work with an app in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with this right now. In your case, if you are only searching by one hashtag at each time you better use instafeed.js

http://instafeedjs.com

I have done this task with this library like this.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: audi',
    clientId: 'XXXXX',
    accessToken: 'XXXXX',
    template: '<li><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></li>'
});
feed.run();
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'ferrari',
    clientId: 'XXXXX',
    accessToken: 'XXXXX',
    template: '<li><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></li>'
});
feed.run();
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'BMW',
    clientId: 'XXXXX',
    accessToken: 'XXXXX',
    template: '<li><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></li>'
});
feed.run();
```

If anyone know how to search by 2 or more hashtags at each time please contact me.

Hope it helps you!